# react-router-dom <Link replace> not working

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So I'm trying to get a hang of the new `react-router-dom`, but I can't get the Link element to work properly: even if I use

```
<Link to={to} replace>
  link
</Link>
```

The destination does not replace the current router location, but it pushes to it.

Do you have any idea how I can get it to replace it?

Comment: Is your `to` variable a string? In any case I think we need more details about this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `but it pushes to it`?

Comment: It adds `{to}` to the url instead of replacing it

Comment: Yes, it is a string, I just used it as a placeholder, in reality I'm not passing a variable